# Ubuntu does not display on my laptop's screen, but does display when connected to TV

Tags: 13.10, wubi, hdmi

I installed Ubuntu 13:10 using the Windows executable through wubi.exe. The image of the OS does not appear on my laptop screen, but when I connect it to a TV via an HDMI cable the image appears normally!

Specs:
⠀Lenovo G400s notebook
⠀Core i3 L3 Cache 2.4 GHz
⠀4GB RAM
⠀500GB hard drive
⠀LCD 14"

Comment: I don't understand what that means. What is an S.O?

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the screen brightness. That worked for me. By default the brightness is set to zero on bootup.